# Browserify npm library

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify, node-modules

I have a well tested npm library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/yuml-diagram) that I would like to Browserify so it can be used in browser applications.

The full source code is here: https://github.com/jaime-olivares/yuml-diagram

I managed to build the library as a monolithic package with the following command line:
`browserify index.js -g uglifyify -o ./dist/yuml-diagram.min.js`

Then I tried to use it in a similar fashion as in Node-JS, as suggested in several places:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jaime-olivares/5cd18b40f2bdcf5e403ed78d181c3d85/raw/00f5624fe30500a22144962184e927236f1ac45f/yuml-diagram.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function loadSvg()
            {
                var yuml_diagram = require('yuml-diagram');

                var yumlText = 
                    `// {type:sequence}
                    [:Computer]async test>>[:Server]
                    [:Computer]sync test>[:Server]`;

                var yuml = new yuml_diagram();
                var svg = yuml.processYumlDocument(yumlText, false);
                document.body.innerHTML = svg;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="loadSvg();">        
    </body>
</html>
```

The `require()` function is not recognized, even if I use the flag `--exports require` in Browserify.

How can I invoke the library's `processYumlDocument()` function from the application script?

Answer (score 0):

Browserify does not add support for require onto your page. Browserify is used on a javascript file that is using resolve internally and produces a version with the resolves statically included.

In your example you should move the content of your script block into a javascript file and then execute browserify on that file. Then include the final produced file in your page.

Comment: Consider this is a library. The application and the library are separated entities. I don't control how the application is built (direct javascript, typescript, etc.) and how big it is. What I need is to find an entry point for invoking processYumlDocument().

Comment: You cant use a module inside a webpage unless you are A. Using a module loader inside the web page that is capable of loading your module. B. The library self registers to the window object on load(Which is terrible behavior but can work in personal projects).

Comment: So how is 'A'  achieved?

Comment: That depends on how you use modules. If you are a browserify user you would write your code in a javascript file and preprocess it with browserify and then serve the completed bundle on your page.

Comment: I mean, from a regular javascript application like in the example above. How I can reach the processYumlDocument() function, either doing something in the html/js or by improving the generation of the browserified library.

Comment: It is a core feature of modules that they are isolated. I am not sure what you are asking anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Found my own answer. It is required the `standalone` parameter in Browserify, as here:

`browserify index.js --standalone yuml_diagram  -g uglifyify -o ./dist/yuml-diagram.min.js`

Where `yuml_diagram` represents the whole bundle. Then the library can be used with a couple of lines:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="../dist/yuml-diagram.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function loadSvg()
            {
                var yumlText = 
                    `// {type:sequence}
                    [:Computer]async test>>[:Server]
                    [:Computer]sync test>[:Server]`;

                // Create the object and invoke a function inside it
                var yuml  = new yuml_diagram();
                var svg = yuml.processYumlDocument(yumlText, false);

                document.body.innerHTML = svg;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="loadSvg();">        
    </body>
</html>
```